# Cross-platform way to play audio files (mp3, wav, etc... ) on Python 3?

Tags: audio, python-3.x

I'm searching for a library (preferably cross-platform) that lets me play various audio files on Python 3 (currently using 3.3.0).

I have tried several options such as Pyglet but it doesn't run on Py3 (I tried the alpha, which SHOULD have Py3 support).

Is there any library ported to Python 3 yet?

Thanks.

Comment: Pyglet runs on Python 3 just fine. I'm using it with 3.3 on a regular basis. Perhaps you [instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) want to ask about your trouble with getting pyglet to work with 3.x?

Comment: I'll look deeper on my troubles with Pyglet then, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyQt4 with Python 3. Qt provides powerful cross-platform multimedia framework.

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

[Here](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Playing%20a%20sound%20with%20QtMultimedia) is playing a sound with QtMultimedia example written for python 2, but it is not difficult to adopt it to python 3. Only be sure, that pyqt4-python3 or similar is installed on your system.

[Here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qaudiooutput.html) is a QAudioOutput class, which solves your problem.

Comment: Your second link is broken. Do you think you could find it somewhere else?